# Gather input in sinch

Tags: java, rest, api, voip, sinch

I want my sinch app to call a number and ask the responder for enter a number to choose his language.

So far I get to make her to make a call with a POST request whose body is :

```
{
                "method" : "ttsCallout",
                "ttsCallout" :
                {
                     "cli" : "xxx",
                     "destination" : { "type" : "number", "endpoint" : "xxx" },
                     "domain" : "pstn",
                     "custom" : "customData",
                     "locale" : "en-US",
                     "prompts" : "#tts[Hello]",
                     "enabledice" : true
                }
          }
```

My question is how can I gather the value that the responder will click on his keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a menu on the ace event
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/index.html#pie